# flutter reactive_forms ReactiveForm.of noSuchMethod

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to disable a submit button in [reactive_forms](https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms)

When I do this code:

```
import 'package:reactive_forms/reactive_forms.dart';
final form = ReactiveForm.of(context);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building VpFormElevatedButton(dirty): The getter 'control' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: control

The relevant error-causing widget was VpFormElevatedButton lib/…/logged_out_nickname/logged_out_nick_name_view.dart:68 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      ReactiveForm.of package:reactive_forms/…/widgets/reactive_form.dart:55
#2      VpFormElevatedButton.build package:vepo/…/buttons/elevated_button_widget.dart:23
#3      StatelessElement.build package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4701
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4627 ... ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════ A RenderFlex overflowed by 99838 pixels on the bottom. The relevant error-causing widget was Column lib/…/logged_out_nickname/logged_out_nick_name_view.dart:65 The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#abc1d relayoutBoundary=up1 OVERFLOWING
```

It thinks `ReactiveForm` is a type:

[image]

`final form = ReactiveForm.of(context);` is copy-pasted from the reactive_forms docs. Why am I seeing this runtime exception?

Comment: Have you check the example of ReactiveForm  https://pub.dev/packages/reactive_forms/example

Comment: @AskNilesh Yes thanks, they are using `ReactiveFormConsumer` in their example, whereas I'm trying to use "Separating Submit Button in a different Widget".

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you have properly assigned the variable and the `NoSuchMethodError` is still thrown with `getter 'value' was called on null`.

Restart or rebuild your app since ***HotReload*** does not call `initState()` and this callback is where variables are assigned, so try rebuilding your app

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The custom button needs to be within the `ReactiveForm(` widget, EG it must be inside:

```
ReactiveForm(
   formGroup: controller.form,
   child: Column(
```

And my button was lower down the page, outside of the `ReactiveForm(`.